# MapBox - Add a clusterGroup clickable with Layer Control

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

I'm still learning and I'm a bit stuck. I may be trying to do to much at once. I have a MapBox map working great with a clickable layer menu taken from examples on the MapBox site.  I also have a MarkerClusterGroup which also works and is always visible on the map. Is there a way I could somehow have the MarkerClusterGroup clickable on/off just like layers identified in var overlays = { ...

Below is the code that I think needs the help:

```
  var layers = {
  Streets: L.mapbox.tileLayer('mapbox.streets').addTo(map),
  Satellite: L.mapbox.tileLayer('mapbox.satellite'),
  Light: L.mapbox.tileLayer('mapbox.light'),
  };

  var overlays = {
  DataA: L.mapbox.featureLayer().loadURL('/data/ctsnew.geojson'),
  DataB: L.mapbox.featureLayer().loadURL('/data/selectZipcodes.geojson'),
  };

// Since featureLayer is an asynchronous method, we use the `.on('ready'`
// call to only use its marker data once we know it is actually loaded.

   Markers: L.mapbox.featureLayer('examples.map-h61e8o8e').on('ready', function(e) {
// The clusterGroup gets each marker in the group added to it
// once loaded, and then is added to the map

   var clusterGroup = new L.MarkerClusterGroup();
   e.target.eachLayer(function(layer) {
       clusterGroup.addLayer(layer);
   });

   map.addLayer(clusterGroup);
   });
```

Could be something as simple as misuse of brackets. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include your Marker Cluster Group in your `overlays` object. For example you could instantiate it just before defining `overlays`, even if your Cluster Group is empty for now.

Then you fill it once it has downloaded its data.

```js
var layers = {
  Streets: L.mapbox.tileLayer('mapbox.streets').addTo(map),
  Satellite: L.mapbox.tileLayer('mapbox.satellite'),
  Light: L.mapbox.tileLayer('mapbox.light'),
};

var clusterGroup = L.markerClusterGroup();

var overlays = {
  DataA: L.mapbox.featureLayer().loadURL('/data/ctsnew.geojson'),
  DataB: L.mapbox.featureLayer().loadURL('/data/selectZipcodes.geojson'),
  Markers: clusterGroup
};

// Since featureLayer is an asynchronous method, we use the `.on('ready'`
// call to only use its marker data once we know it is actually loaded.

L.mapbox.featureLayer('examples.map-h61e8o8e').on('ready', function(e) {
  // The clusterGroup gets each marker in the group added to it
  // once loaded, and then is added to the map

  e.target.eachLayer(function(layer) {
    clusterGroup.addLayer(layer);
  });

  map.addLayer(clusterGroup); // use that line if you want to automatically add the cluster group to the map once it has downloaded its data.
});
```